# How to trigger an action after saving record in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, action

I got a simple app where users can create `projects` and `timetrackers` which `belong_to` the `projects` and are basically timestamps. `timetrackers` have a `start_time` and an `end_time`(both :datetime), now i want to calulate the duration between the two values and save it into `timespan` which is :float.

for this i got a `set_timespan` action in my `timetrackers_controller`

```
  def set_timespan
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @timetracker = Timetracker.find(params[:id])

    @timetracker.timespan = (@timetracker.end_time - @timetracker.start_time).round / 3600
  end
```

The Create action

```
  def create
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @timetrackers = @job.timetrackers.new(timetracker_params)
    @timetrackers.user_id = current_user.id
    @timetrackers.job_id = @job.id
    #set_timespan


    respond_to do |format|
      if @timetrackers.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Timestamps created successfully.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to new_timetracker_path, notice: "Please fill out the form." }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

when i try to shoot the action in my `create` action just before `@timetrackers.save`, i get a `Couldn't find Timetracker without an ID` Error. Also I get redirected to `jobs/3/timetrackers`. Why is the ID not found and how can i properly trigger an action in my controller to calculate the timespan? Later i want to sum up the timespans.

Comment: can you show your code inside method create, (timetrackers_controller.rb)

Comment: @widjajayd sure. i edited the post. the action call is commented out since its not working at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll still have access to the `@timetrackers` instance variable, so as a simple solution:

```
def set_timespan
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])

  @timetrackers.timespan = (@timetracker.end_time - @timetracker.start_time).round / 3600
end
```

I'd take this a step further and remove the method altogether, as `@job` is also available and just use the pertinent line directly in the create action:

```
def create
  # ...
  @timetrackers.job_id = @job.id
  # v here v
  @timetrackers.timespan = (@timetrackers.end_time - @timetrackers.start_time).round / 3600

  respond_to do |format|
  # ...
end
```

As a final, perhaps ideal solution, you can use a [`before_create`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback in your `Timespan` model:

```
# timespan.rb
before_create -> { self.timespan = (end_time - start_time).round / 3600 }
```

That way, your `timespan` will be set automatically as it's created.

Comment: calling it directly in the create action leads to an undefined method for `end_time` Nil:class stuff

Comment: Ah - that's because you're using a pluralised `@timetrackers` in the `create` method @GabrielTheCode. Try the above now :) Actually, if I were you I'd definitely try the `before_create` approach - that's the most 'Railsy' way of doing things.

Comment: its so hot where i am at the moment and i completely forgot about this. ill try before_create.

Comment: Ha, it's easily done :) Let me know how you get on, and please feel free to upvote / accept if this does what you're after @GabrielTheCoder.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you have an answer you already like, but...

Another approach would be to groom your `timetracker_params` so that they include all the appropriate data using a method like `new_timetracker_attributes`. Something, perhaps, like:

```
  def create
    @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
    @timetrackers = @job.timetrackers.new(new_timetracker_attributes)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @timetrackers.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Timestamps created successfully.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to new_timetracker_path, notice: "Please fill out the form." }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private 

  def new_timetracker_attributes
    timetracker_params.merge(
      user_id:  current_user.id,
      timespan: ((end_time-start_time).round/3600)
    )
  end

  def timetracker_params
    params.require(:timetracker).permit(:start_time, :end_time)
  end

  def start_time
    timetracker_params[:start_time]
  end

  def end_time
    timetracker_params[:end_time]
  end
```

There are many ways you could groom your `timetracker_params` and this is just one idea.

The point is, you have *all* of your new instance attribute set up going on in *one place* instead of smeared in various places across your application. IMO, it makes it a wee bit easier to understand what is going on and debug if things go pear shaped.

Comment: interesting approach. i like the idea but it seem to make the controller a bit heavier.

Comment: I guess it adds 6 lines (or so). There are almost always tradeoffs.